# IdentityServer4 and Web API .NET 4.6.2

Tags: owin, identityserver3, identityserver4

Is there a OWIN middleware that can work with a standard .NET 4.6.2 (not Core) framework to valide tokens coming from IdentityServer4.

Something like 
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation

Answer (score 2):

A bug has solved and now by upgrading IdentityServer3.Accesstokenvalidation to "v2.13.0" you can work with tokens come from Idsv4.

for more detail:

> https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation/issues/124

Comment: Due to the required compatibility with IdentityModel, do we have to downgrade our IdentityModel from 3.3.1 to 2.0.0 in our 4.6.1 project? Thanks

Comment: The downgrade is preventing me from using this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the project README.md says `OWIN Middleware to validate access tokens from IdentityServer v3`. It should in theory still work with IDS4 tokens:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation